# Safe for inner AsyncTask to access outer Activity class private member fields?

Tags: java, android, thread-safety, android-asynctask, inner-classes

Is it safe for an Android AsyncTask that's an inner class of an Activity to read the Activity's private member fields while in AsyncTask.doInBackground()?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too generic a question, is the private member field final?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, no. If the activity is undergoing a configuration change and is being destroyed and recreated, your background thread will be talking to the wrong instance, which may cause problems for you.

Ideally, the `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask` should be able to run independently of its launching component (activity, service, etc.). I suggest that you create a constructor on your `AsyncTask` and pass in whatever is needed. Or, have the `AsyncTask` be managed by a dynamic fragment that uses `setRetainInstance()`, in which case (AFAIK) it should be safe for the task to access private data members of the *fragment*, since the fragment is not going anywhere.

Comment: Very good point, that made me think (and will probably lead to some refactoring in my projects...)

Comment: @CommonsWare So it can cause problems, but these are not due to threading, specifically memory consistency errors.  Is that right?

Comment: @Julian: Well, memory consistency errors *are* due to threading.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, I wasn't clear.  What I was trying to ask is whether the problems caused by the AsyncTask's background thread talking to the wrong Activity instance is an example of a threading memory consistency error?

Comment: @Julian: In a manner of speaking, sure. In this case, it's not that two threads are trying to manipulate the same data at the same time (the sort of thing you solve by synchronization). It's more that your background thread is oblivious to the changing environment, and even if you teach it about the changes (e.g., in `onCreate()` of the new activity instance), that might be too late.

Answer (score 0):

when an inner classes access private members (fields or functions) of the enclosing class, the compiler will generate accessor functions to those members. this will be breaking of encapsulation, some argue if it is a Good Thing or a Bad Thing.